# How do i use a proxy with AXIOS?

Tags: javascript, proxy, axios

I am trying to use NORDVPN servers for proxy. I can get it working if i use a socks client but i want to use the normal servers (if possible).

```
const getIpUrl = "https://api.ipify.org?format=json";

export const requestCurrentIp = () =>
  axios.get(getIpUrl, {
    httpsAgent: tunnel.httpsOverHttps({
      proxy: {
        host: vpn,
        port: 89,
        proxyAuth: `${username}:${password}`,
      },
    }),
  });
```

When i do this, i get this message:

```
tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Hostname/IP does not match certificate's 
altnames:
Host: api.ipify.org. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.nordvpn.com, DNS:nordvpn.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either consider using a different proxy server that is compatible with 'api.ipify.org' or make NordVPN compatible with the 'api.ipify.org' server.

You can make NordVPN compatible by using its dedicated proxy servers. These are specifically designed for proxying HTTP/HTTPS traffic and have SSL certificates that are valid for the domains you want to access. To use these servers, you will need to find the server hostname and port number. You can find this on NordVPN's website or by contacting their customer support. Once you have taht you can modify your code to something like this:

```
const nordvpnProxyUrl = "https://<nordvpn-proxy-server-hostname>:<port>";

export const requestCurrentIp = () =>
  axios.get(getIpUrl, {
    httpsAgent: tunnel.httpsOverHttps({
      proxy: {
        host: nordvpnProxyUrl,
        proxyAuth: `${nordvpnUsername}:${nordvpnPassword}`,
      },
    }),
  });
```

**Not Recommended Way:**
Another thing you might do is disable SSL verification for this request, but this is makes your connection less secure, so this is not reccomeneded. But if you were to do this you can use something like this :

```
export const requestCurrentIp = () =>
  axios.get(getIpUrl, {
    httpsAgent: tunnel.httpsOverHttps({
      proxy: {
        host: vpn,
        port: 89,
        proxyAuth: `${username}:${password}`,
      },
    }),
    // disable SSL verification for this request
    https: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
axios.request({
  url: 'https://google.com',
  method: 'get|post|delete....',
  proxy: {
    host: 'https://yourvpnproxy.com',
    port: 123,
    auth: {
      username: 'yourauthusername',
      password: '123'
    }
  }
})
```

I had some problems in some tests I've made while calling `https` urls with some proxies, if this happens to you try changing your url to `http` and see if it works. But this will make your requests a little less secure... to me this was not a problem but it may be to you